# How do I open Gdevelop with Termux? Is it even possible?

Tags: gdevelop

I use a samsung chromebook 3 and I am trying to get the FULL version of Gdevelop. I installed it for linux, and I dragged it to be one of my termux files. I am trying to run a command in termux that opens the full version of gdevelop. But it keeps saying: "NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY" Is there a command I can run in termux to open the full version of Gdevelop?

Comment: My first hit on a web search of "gdevelop chromebook" gives [How to install Gdevelop on a Chromebook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBokGy2CUOE).

Comment: No, I mean without enableing linux. Most videos are how to do it WITH the linux feture.

Comment: The supported OSs for GDevelop are Windows, MacOS & Linux. Termux is not a full Linux distro & geared toward Linux CLI usage. If you want to run GDevelop on the ChromeOS, your best bet is probably to use their [on-line editor](https://editor.gdevelop-app.com).